# What is getting verified (authenticated) in Windows Authentication?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have windows authentication enabled in asp.net mvc as below.

```
  <authentication mode="Windows">
  </authentication>
```

I read the below statement in Wikipedia.

> Integrated Windows Authentication itself is not a standard or an authentication protocol.`

So, what is actually getting verified when we use Windows Authentication?

**References**

`You can use Windows authentication when your IIS 7 server runs on a corporate network that is using Microsoft Active Directory service domain identities or other Windows accounts to identify users. Because of this, you can use Windows authentication whether or not your server is a member of an Active Directory domain.
Windows authentication (formerly named NTLM, and also referred to as Windows NT Challenge/Response authentication) is a secure form of authentication because the user name and password are hashed before being sent across the network.`

`Integrated Windows Authentication itself is not a standard or an authentication protocol. Integrated Windows Authentication works with most modern  web browsers,but does not work over HTTP proxy servers. Therefore, it is best for use in intranets where all the clients are within a single domain. It may work with other Web browsers if they have been configured to pass the user's logon credentials to the server that is requesting authentication.`

Comment: Please explain what you actually want to know. _"What is actually getting verified"_ is a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

It depens on the actual protocol.

In basic authentication, username/password are sent to the server.
In digest, hash is sent, however digest is rarely used as it requires plain password at the active directory side and although it can be turned on, no one uses it.
In ntlm, a negotiation is held between user, server and the AD.
In kerberos, the browser first obtains an auth ticket from AD and then sends it for validation.

All so called "Windows" authentication schemes are based on the 401 Challenge flow supported by browsers and it is interesting to know that with a custom module, you don't really need the AD for the 401 flow but you can use any custom user backstore.

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2013/11/basic-authentication-module-with-custom.html